# How should a dhcp server allocate only one ip address?

Tags: linux, centos, dhcp, dhcp-server, centos-8

*How should I configure the dhcpd.conf file so the DHCP server would allocate **only one** IP address from a subnet to the first VM that is connecting to the DHCP server? Thank you.*

Operating system: CentOS 8

**EDIT**
Based upon feedback.

The DHCP needs to limit the leasing to just one IP address for that specific range `range dynamic-bootp 192.168.101.10 192.168.101.100`. After one ip address is allocated, there will be no more allocations, for that range.
"First come, first served."

```
Current configuration:

option domain-name      "project.local";
option domain-name-servers      192.168.101.1;
default-lease-time 3600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.101.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers 192.168.101.1;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.101.255;
        option ntp-servers 192.168.101.1;
        pool {
          range dynamic-bootp 192.168.101.10 192.168.101.100;
          allow unknown-clients;
        class "limited-1" {
          lease limit 1;
        }
 }

}
```

Comment: A DHCP server will usually allocate the first IP in the range the first time it is solicited.

Comment: Do you just want the VM to have a certain IP? If so, why not just give the VM a static IP?

Comment: Untested: give it a pool of one address.

Comment: @NasirRiley - I'd assumed this was some kind of race condition - only the first to ask can have an address. I could be wrong, it is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Tetsujin Perhaps.

Comment: I've never tried this as I don't know why anyone would do it, but I imagine all you need to do is change the range line to "dynamic-bootp 192.168.101.10 192.168.101.10"

Comment: @davidgo the range has to stay the same; no modification as far as range. The configuration is for experimental purposes.

Comment: What you are asking makes no sense. You might be able to specify the same single IP for multiple hosts by adding definitions for each hosts MAC address. Never tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that I was looking for. Let me explain based upon the configuration I posted below.

- I defined a class - "limited-1" that would lease just one IP-address - "First come, first served".
- Then I defined a pool - this pool would allow members of the class - "limited 1" to the specified range.
- I also created a second pool - to test the fact that members of the second class would get IP-addresses from range 101-200. If this pool is not specified, the dhcp would not allocate IP-addresses to those outside of the "limit-1" class.

This was conducted for testing purposes.

```
option domain-name      "project.local";
option domain-name-servers      ns.project.local;
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.101.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
option broadcast-address 192.168.101.255;
option ntp-servers ntpa.project.local;
option routers 192.168.101.1;

class "limited-1" {
       lease limit 1;
       default-lease-time 3600;
       max-lease-time 7200;
            }
pool {
       allow members of "limited-1";
       range dynamic-bootp 192.168.101.10 192.168.101.100;
 }

pool {
       range dynamic-bootp 192.168.101.101 192.168.101.200;
       default-lease-time 3600;
       max-lease-time 7200;
    }
}
```